Constrained Optimization over Uncomputable Functions
I have two non-computable functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ and am investigating the maximum of $F(x)$ subject to the constraint that $G(x)=0$. That is, I am interested in the quantity $\max_{x:G(x)=0} [F(x)]$.
If these were computable, analytic functions, then (provided other conditions were satisfied) one could use Lagrange mutlipliers and solve the equation $\nabla F(x) - \lambda \nabla G(x)=0 $. Roughly speaking, this allows a constrained optimization problem to be re-framed as an unconstrained optimization.
I am wondering if some equivalent claim can be made for non-computable functions which cannot be differentiated. In particular, I am wondering under what conditions the following (or something similar) is true:
$\text{max}_{x}[F(x)-G(x)] = \max_{x:G(x)=0}[F(x)]$
Here, the left hand side represents unconstrained optimization (which should probably have a $\lambda$ or something as well) and the right hand side is the constrained optimization.
